# Whatsapp folder in /data/ parition gone

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery

I was reflashing **CM10.2** on my **GT-i9300**.
(Also did a backup with CWM 6 but the data partition was not backuped, which I did not noticed..)
I booted the new Rom and installed Titanium Backup to recover my apps but my all kinds of services crashed...
So I decided to upgrade to **CM11** (And forgot to wipe after flashing)

Now I got a bootloop...(which is not the problem because I think afer a full wipe i will be able to start my phone again normaly)

But first i want a full backup of my /data/ partition.
So I connected the phone via ADB and the backup went through. **BUT** the whatsapp folder and so my chat history, pictures etc. are just gone!
I did not find any record of it?!?

So, do any of you know why? oder 
is it possible to recover it somehow?
are they some hidden mirror partitions?

best regards
Chris

Comment: The WA folder with your chats, pictures, etc. is not stored in `/data`, but on the (internal) SD card. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I copied the whole sdcard via ADB with "adb pull /sdcard/"